# Performance over HttpResponse handling

Tags: java, android, json, http, gson

I'm using the [Resting](https://code.google.com/p/resting/) API to query a REST API that returns JSON.
The API handles the org.apache.http.HttpResponse that way (simplified for brevity, full code [here](https://code.google.com/p/resting/source/browse/trunk/resting/src/com/google/resting/component/impl/ServiceResponse.java)):

```
Header[] responseHeaders = response.getAllHeaders();
InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
IContentData contentData = IOUtils.writeToContentData(inputStream, charset);
```

IOUtils.writeToContentData stores the response content as a string. Because I intend to parse that string as JSON immediately, I thought I would avoid the string copy and parse the JSON on the fly, like this:

```
Header[] responseHeaders = response.getAllHeaders();
InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
JsonElement contentData = new JsonParser().parse(new JsonReader(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))));
```

The JsonParser and JsonReader are both from the gson library.
I've done a few tests and it seems that the second code is faster and generates less GC but this is very non-scientific - and tested on my Android Nexus 4 only.

I'm wondering if I have missed something given that Resting and other libraries that I've checked all seem to make a copy of the string and start parsing afterwards only. Any evidence or opinion on the performance of these?

Comment: Yours should be faster, but others may not care very much about the performance difference between the two.

Comment: They may not that's true. To give a little bit of context, I'm retrieving JSON contents that weight around 100Ko; the device has become the performance bottleneck, the parsing taking about 0.3 to 0.5 seconds - on my device.

Comment: yes, optimization becomes necessary in your case.